# Tsql joins on sql server

Tags: sql-server, join

What type of joins would you use if you were trying to find missing data in two related tables? Would it be an inner join or an outer join?

Comment: I think trying it yourself will yield the answer. If not, add the code attempt to your question. Questions that make no attempt at a solution attract downvotes.

Comment: I would use neither. I would use a NOT EXISTS query.

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 2):

A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with an additional `WHERE` clause could be used but in my opinion, the better ways to do this is by using `NOT EXISTS`

**Lets say we have one table with all the values and one table with some missing values**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableAllValues(id int , val varchar(255));
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableMissingValues(id int, val varchar(255));

INSERT INTO dbo.TableAllValues(id,val)
VALUES(1,'Value1'),(2,'Value2'),(3,'Value3');

INSERT INTO dbo.TableMissingValues(id,val)
VALUES(1,'Value1'),(2,'Value2');
```

**You could do it with a left join**

```
SELECT av.id,av.val 
FROM dbo.TableAllValues av
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TableMissingValues mv 
ON av.id = mv.id 
WHERE mv.id IS NULL;
```

**Result**

```
id  val
3   Value3
```

**Or you could use not exists**

```
SELECT ID,val FROM dbo.TableAllValues av
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM dbo.TableMissingValues mv  
                  WHERE av.id = mv.id);
```

**Why is `NOT EXISTS` better?**

It is better from a performance standpoint.

When using the left join, it will first use a join operator to match the values and afterwards apply the filter using a filter operator (`where mv.id IS NULL`).

The `NOT EXISTS` will use the  `LEFT ANTI SEMI JOIN` operator in the plan to immediately filter the results.

More on the `LEFT ANTI SEMI JOIN` operator and why `LEFT JOIN` could perform worse [here](https://sqlity.net/en/1360/a-join-a-day-the-left-anti-semi-join/)

---

**Regarding the question:**

> Matching one column to another ONE column from the other table to see
>   which data is missing from them both since they both reference the
>   same data

**Getting non matching values from both tables with `UNION ALL`**

*Add an extra record to the test table*

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TableMissingValues(id,val)
VALUES(4,'Value4')
```

*Not exists*

```
SELECT ID,val FROM dbo.TableAllValues av
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from  dbo.TableMissingValues mv  where av.id = mv.id)
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,val FROM dbo.TableMissingValues mv
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from  dbo.TableAllValues av  where av.id = mv.id);
```

*Left join*

```
SELECT av.id,av.val FROM dbo.TableAllValues av
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableMissingValues mv on av.id = mv.id 
where mv.id is null
UNION ALL
SELECT mv.id,mv.val FROM dbo.TableMissingValues mv
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableAllValues av on av.id = mv.id 
where av.id is null;
```

**Result**

```
id  val
3   Value3
4   Value4
```

*The record with `id` = 3 is the record missing from `TableMissingValues` and the record with `id` = 4 is the record missing from `TableAllValues`.*

Comment: So what if two columns from both related tables were referencing the same data? Do i still use left join and not exists?

Comment: @Ujji Do you mean that you need to match two columns from table A against two columns from table B? I would still use the not exists but with an AND to match both. I will update the answer.

Comment: Matching one column to another ONE column from the other table to see which data is missing from them both since they both reference the same data. Thanks

Comment: @Uji okay I think I understand what you mean, getting the missing values from both  A and B? I will add it to the answer

Comment: @Ujji glad it helped, try and add a bit more information next time to not get downvoted. For instance, an example of the tables and resultset you would like would make you not get downvoted and get you an answer sooner, win-win :).